# SAS append to existing option

Tags: sas

I used Table Loader transformation (append to existing) and received following error:
"Decryption/Decompression failure".
Is there another option to add rows to current dataset ?

Comment: SAS has a wide range of products starting with SAS Base Code... I would presume that you are using the SAS Data Integration Studio and you are talking about the "Table Loader" node. If so, you should add these information to your question.

Comment: You used "table loader transformation" in what interface?  SAS/Studio? Enterprise Guide? Data Integration Studio? Something else?  Did you just try writing actual SAS code?  PROC APPEND for example?

Comment: I use Data Integration and this is simple transformation „Table loader” append to existing option